# Why is the transformation law for tangent space coordinate basis vectors "easily seen" using the chain rule?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, smooth-manifolds, general-relativity

In Spacetime & Geometry, Carrol immediately posits that, given that you have some tangent space vector (in the coordinate basis representation):

$\frac{d}{d\lambda}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\partial _{\mu}$

then the basis vectors $\partial _{\mu}$ will transform according to the chain rule:
$\partial _{\mu '} =\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\mu '}} \partial _{\mu}$

But this doesn't seem immediately obvious to me. I thought I would motivate it like this: say we have coordinates that are related by $x^{\mu '}=x^{\mu '}(x^{\mu})$ and for some smooth function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and some directional derivative $d / d\lambda$ we have (using the chain rule):
\begin{align}\frac{df}{d\lambda}&=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}} \\
&=\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\mu '}} \frac{d x^{\mu '}}{d x^{\lambda}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu '}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu'}}{\partial x^{\mu }}
\end{align}

From which we can identify:
$\partial _{\mu}=\frac{\partial x^{\mu'}}{\partial x^{\mu }} \partial _{\mu '}$

and thus:
$\partial _{\mu '}=\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\mu '}} \partial _{\mu }$

Is this a good motivation? Also, it is not clear to me when to use total and partial derivatives here. I felt that anything w.r.t. $\lambda$ should be a total derivative, but I am not sure why.

*My first approach was some convolved diagram with multiple coordinate charts on my manifold and then somehow using that to set up some equation but that turned out to be a huge mess.*

Comment: Yes, that seems like a good motivation.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but possibly of interest: [Dual space and covectors: force, work and energy](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501802)

Comment: What's the protocol on accidentally answering your own question on SE? Do I just copy-paste and accept?