# Why do we define $dx$ as a linear functional, but also use a similar notation in local coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry

Why do we try to define $dx$ as a linear functional from the tangent space to the real numbers when we use a similar notation for the local coords on the tangent space?

Example, let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $T_pM$ be its tangent space at $p$. Then the linear functional $dx: T_pM \to R$ maps $t \in T_pM$ to $t^i$, $dx^i(t) = t^i$. But when describing the basis vectors on $T_pM$ we write the local coordinates as $\left ( d/dx_i\right)$, so we use $dx_i$ in the bottom too.

Comment: Shouldn't you really be using $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$?

Comment: @Bye_World, sure but that doesn't answer what $\partial  x_i$ now.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem.  $dx^i$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ are distinct enough notations that no one is going to confuse one for the other.  As to why we use those particular notations, it's just because they're convenient.  Look around the site a bit and you'll see some explanations.

Comment: @Hawk: To clarify, writing a tangent vector with respect to $d/dx_{i}$ requires you to _fix a local coordinate system_; this isn't an intrinsic construction on the tangent space of a manifold. Are you asking why we use differential operator notation to denote vector fields in coordinates, and why we use differential notation to denote cotangent vectors...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, yeah. We are essentially using the same thing, but we are just 'hiding' it by cosmetically changing the notations.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment, but the "differential" notations come from classical (pre-20th Century) calculus, and are motivated by the chain rule. Spivak (in both _Calculus on Manifolds_ and _A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry_ Vol. I) explains this perspective in detail, see also [Dual space and covectors: force, work and energy](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501802/).